# Android Push Notifications Using Sinch and Parse

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, sinch

I'm looking at the push notifications tutorial for Android here: https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/send-push-notifications-android-messaging-app-using-gcm/, and I'm wondering how can I apply the same logic but instead of using the backend provided, use the Parse backend.

```
   //url of where your backend is hosted, can't be local!
   HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://your-domain.com?reg_id=" + regId);
```

So I'd like to use Parse but what would I put in the arguments for the HttpPost constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the parse tutorial https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications and post the pushpairs, have you checked out our ManagedPush? Its super simple
https://www.sinch.com/learn/sinch-managed-push-calling-android/ no need for parse or your own backend

Comment: Oh that makes things easier. Thanks!